# Is there a way to get the memory pool in order of newest first?

Tags: php, bitcoin-cli, getmemorypool

I'm trying to list out the results of `getrawmempool` by *newest transactions first*.

**Here's what I've got:**

`getrawmempool` returns the memory pool in order of *transaction hash*, so I'm using PHP to sort it:

```
<?php
// Get an array of the memory pool transactions
$getrawmempool = $bitcoin->getrawmempool(true); // true = verbose

// Create a new array of "txid" => "time" (just so I can sort it)
foreach (array_keys($getrawmempool) as $txid) {
     $mempool[$tx] = $getrawmempool[$txid]['time'];
}

// Sort the new array
arsort($mempool);

// Print results
print_r($mempool);
?>
```

Now, this isn't terribly slow, but sorting 10,000+ array values isn't terribly snappy.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way of getting the mempool in order of *newest first* from bitcoin-cli?
- If not, is there a faster/better way of sorting the returned results?

I'd like to play around with all the mempool transactions using PHP. So if I can get the mempool transactions in order along with all the verbose information about each one, that would be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two options:

**1)** Patch bitcoin-core and make `getrawmempoolentry` return the mempool transaction sorted after entry_date. There is boost multi index that would be capable to fast sort the mempool transaction (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/txmempool.h#L303)

**2)** You can try to improve your PHP sort speed. IMHO `Arsort` is not the best choice.